# Magic Mouse can never reconnect on Yosemite

Tags: macos, bluetooth, mouse

Since upgrading to Yosemite (did a wipe of my HD before installing, so no settings was there from Mavericks) I can only connect my Magic Mouse normally once per boot.

Normally you would be able to connect the mouse, sleep the computer, connect the mouse again, however I have to reboot my MacBook Pro after the sleep, if I want the Magic Mouse to work again.

I can see the device in both the Bluetooth preference pane and the Bluetooth menubar icon dropdown, but clicking connect in either of them does nothing.
[image]
[image]

Sometimes deleting the pairing and re-pairing with the mouse works, however most of the time it doesn't.

I have tried to reset my nvram and deleting `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist`, without any success.

When using Mavericks and below, I have never had any issue with my Magic Mouse and the problem still exist when using a different Magic Mouse on Yosemite.

Any suggestion on how to fix this, without downgrading to Mavericks?

Comment: Have you tried performing an SMC reset yet?

Comment: I would try reinstalling the OS then through the Recovery Partition. This will not delete you personal information but just reinstall the core system files.

Comment: @ProfFrnswrth reinstalling OS X didn't solve the problem.

Comment: A similar question with some console logs is http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156863/

Comment: Try to hold mouse button for 2 secs after your Mac woke up. My MagicMouse connects after this. May be side effect of intentional design to save battery while idle or something.

Comment: Sounds insane, but add the USB extension cord to your USB keyboard.  Then it pairs again.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

I found a solution from [this comment on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/2jo6b8/osx_yosemite_causing_problems_with_magic_trackpad/clf93lj):

1. Turn off wifi
2. Reconnect Magic Mouse
3. Turn on wifi again

I just noticed that the above doesn't work sometimes and instead you have to reconnect the mouse after turning on wifi again:

1. Turn off wifi
2. Turn on wifi again
3. Reconnect Magic Mouse

Comment: I have a coworker who had/has this issue and this fixed it for him (if only temporarily). Thanks!

Comment: Seriously Apple??

Comment: Fixed the issue for me too, with Yosemite, on a Mid-2012 Macbook.  I'd like to join the "Seriously Apple??" choir.

Comment: Can confirm that temporarily disabling Wifi achieves the pairing for me. Looks like a bug in the networking middleware... I expect better from Apple.

Comment: this worked for me... until now i used to log off and login to reconnect back to magic mouse. Apple -> (facepalm)

Comment: Holy cow, this worked. I've been searching for this for months. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisHatton: ...I don't :)

Comment: You total legend, been suffering with this for months.  As soon as I switched of WiFI a pairing request appeared. Thank you.

Comment: Right. you have to turn off wifi. This problem waste my first hour almost every Monday morning. Seem the devices forget everything after a weekend break.

Comment: Apple has gotten worse and worse....

Comment: Incidentally, I was having the problem when my WiFi was turned off, and the OPPOSITE cycling of WiFi fixes the problem for me. So turn WiFi on, then off... then reconnect Magic Mouse. I find all Apple products to be getting worse and worse throughout the years. Shame there really isn't a better product.

Comment: I'd like to join the "seriously Apply?" train.  I'm so glad my $2600 laptop that just works is living up to it's name /s

Comment: Confirmed this has been working everytime on Yosemite!

Comment: Experienced this issue for the first time this morning. I tried the usual things and only cycling the WiFi fixed it. I'm running El Cap for what it's worth.

Comment: Great! a big thank you!
This is the same level as the "connect your keyboard via the extender otherwise it won't get your mac out of sleep"! http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/102170/179540

Comment: Are you serious Apple?!! Still an issue on El Cap, still solves it on El Cap

Comment: Thank you.  I've been fighting this for years through multiple versions of OS X.  I'm adding this comment because I don't see anyone else mentioning that this fixes the issue for Sierra--it does.

Answer (score 18):

I've had issues reconnecting my bluetooth keyboard & trackpad since upgrading to Yosimite.
I run this script via custom Automator Application:

1. Search for (Spotlight search) and run Automator
2. Choose "Application" for new file type
3. Click on "Utilities" from list
4. Double-Click "Run AppleScript"
5. Replace (* Your script goes here *) with:

   ```
   do shell script "kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport; 
   kextload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport" with administrator privileges
   ```
6. Press play to test (will prompt for password)
7. File->Save to desktop or wherever

Run the automator app whenever bluetooth devices won't connect

Comment: This works. I have made a script to install sleepwatcher and run those to commands every time the computer wakes from sleep, which has completely eliminated the problem from me: https://gist.github.com/Tyilo/c92684d277acb62272b5

Comment: @Tyilo That's an excellent suggestion! The only time I have problems with bluetooth is precisely after waking the macbook from sleep. Thanks!

Comment: I was getting syntax, and totally unfamiliar with apple script to me a minute to realize that the line breaks above are invalid, and the com.apple.... must follow right after -b for both.  Otherwise you get missing argument errors.   (also it did not solve the problem :( ) And this horrible hack is still the only way i suceed http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157357/yosemite-magic-mouse-and-a-bluetooth-disconnection-party/157359#157359

Comment: @Eddie, sorry about that, you are correct, formatting got messed up, causing syntax error, I've updated that, however, yes, this only works for some cases

Comment: Finally! This should be the selected answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! I 'converted' it to shell script since I always have a terminal open and typing is faster than searching for the app and clicking. Just needs prepending `sudo`: 
`sudo kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport; 
sudo kextload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport`

Answer (score 7):

For many it is because of a [WiFi/Bluetooth conflict](http://osxdaily.com/2015/02/18/remove-bluetooth-pan-wi-fi-conflict-os-x-yosemite/).

1. Go to the  Apple menu and choose System Preferences
2. Go to the Network control panel
3. Select “Bluetooth PAN” from the list of network interfaces on the left side menu
4. Hit the Delete key or the [-] minus button to remove the Bluetooth PAN interface

Note: *Bluetooth PAN is for connecting to your iPhone for things like "Instant Hotspot" and can easily be re-added using the [+] on the same screen if you need it later.*

Comment: This worked! +1 for disabling features I don't use anyway.

Comment: The mouse stubbornly refused to connect, even with fresh batteries, until I deleted the Bluetooth PAN. Then it connected immediately after I turned Bluetooth off and on. We'll see how it does.

Answer (score 2):

This will sound insane, and I admit that, but it worked for me for some reason.

If I used the USB extension cord with my usb keyboard, the pair option magically reappeared in bluetooth.  I can only assume it has to do with grounding, but it is worth 2 secs to try and find out if it might work for you.

[image: usb extension cord]

Comment: I can confirm this also worked for me. Nevertheless this is insane and I will send the mouse back.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I think I spotted a possible cause of the problem. My mouse was called "My Name's mouse" with the apostrophe, maybe that was causing the errors.

I have changed the name to avoid using spaces and special characters, now is called just "mymouse" and I don't seem to have the problem anymore.

Comment: I think your solution works. I'll test a few days to see if it works.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work anyway, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

@Tyilo suggestion works. Get this script:
https://gist.github.com/Tyilo/c92684d277acb62272b5

Just remember to first `chmod` your .sh file to be executable. For example:

```
$ cd your_scripts_dir
$ chmod u+x yosemite-bluetooth-fix.sh
```

then you may run it as:

```
$ ./yosemite-bluetooth-fix.sh
```

Then simply close your lid or make the Mac go to sleep, upon wake up, the Bluetooth icon will appear weird, and will be set as "not available", but a few seconds later your Magic Mouse will be back.

Comment: Although this works sometimes, it only has a success rate of about 80%, whereas turning wifi off and on seems to work every time.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get my magic mouse to reconnect after I changed the batteries.  All I had to do was turn off wifi and it immediately recognized the bluetooth mouse.  No idea why this works, but it did.
I am using a 15"retina MB pro with Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off and then back on Bluetooth worked for me.

Settings -> Bluetooth -> Turn Off/On

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to connect a Magic Mouse 2 (The version with the Lightning connector) I had the Lightning-to-USB cable connected to a Thunderbolt display. The mouse would not show up in the Bluetooth pane or the Mouse pane of System Preferences. On a whim, I tried plugging the USB end directly to the MacBook. It paired the mouse immediately. Trying to connect through the Thunderbolt display seemed to prevent the initial pairing. Other hubs might prevent the same thing.

tl/dr: Plug the mouse DIRECTLY into the laptop.

Answer (score -1):

Turning off wifi fixed the problem.

1. Turn off the wifi.
2. Mouse will be discovered automatically.