# Magic Mouse 2 Only Connects When Plugged In

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I have a Magic Mouse 2 - the type that can be connected to my laptop with a Lightning cable, and a Retina MBP 15-inch Mid 2015 running Sierra (10.12.3).

My mouse does not connect via Bluetooth. Power cycling the mouse, the computer itself, the bluetooth, and the wifi does nothing. I've also tried un-pairing the mouse as well. I followed every step of every answer on [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154837/magic-mouse-can-never-reconnect-on-yosemite) already.

However, when I plug in the mouse with my lightning cable, the mouse is immediately recognized as my mouse, and even has a 88% charge on it. The moment I unplug the mouse, it is disconnected and unrecognizable.

Help?

Comment: When it wont connect, try turning off your wifi and try again. This always works for me when my Magic Mouse isn't powered on at bootup for my laptop. It won't connect after I turn the mouse on but I recently learned that turning off wifi will get it to connect rather than rebooting

Answer (score 2):

I removed the device completely and added again, connected without issue. When I tried connecting it would flash connected/disconnected in bluetooth preferences. Wasted like an hour trying different cables/chargers...

Answer (score 1):

It may be an issue with one of the bluetooth radios.

Can your MBP connect to other BT devices?
 - If not, you may need to get your MBP to Apple Service.

Can you connect the MM2 to a different computer via BT?
 - If not, you may need to get your MM2 to Apple Service.

If you can't test this yourself, you should get both units to an Apple store and let them diagnose it for you.  They are usually pretty good at root-causing such issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your power is too low, Connect to cable, Remove from settings, then let it charge then connect again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same type of problem with my wireless keyboard, it would only work when plugged or connected to my Mac by a lightning cable.
I was able to solve it by disconnecting the Magic Keyboard and reconnecting again.

Answer (score 0):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7689530 The answer here worked for my magic keyboard and I'm sure it applies to the mouse/trackpad as well.

-First connect your magic keyboard/trackpad with your mac using a lightning cable(in case if it was not already)

-Turn off your bluetooth from system preferences( you will have to use a wired mouse if you are doing it in a imac or mac mini)

-toggle the keyboard/trackpad power to "off"

-disconnect the lightning cable

-Now turn on bluetooth from system preferences

-Then, toggle the keyboard/trackpad power to "on"

-It will connect and work without any issues